# Можно ли заставить вложенный класс работать через hover внутри тега <a>?

Tags: html, css

Через `li` с классом работает или дивом, а внутри тега `a`?

```css
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline;
}

a:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#home">Home</a>
<a href="#news">News</a>
<a class="dropdown" href="javascript:void(0)">Dropdown
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
<a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
</a>
<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто поместите код меню не в `a` a в `div`, a ссылка пусть остается:

```css
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#home">Home</a>
<a href="#news">News</a>
<div class="dropdown" href="javascript:void(0)">
  <a href="#">Dropdown Link</a>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>
```